# OpenShift: Can I set up a build that copies a docker image from an imagestream to an external docker repository?

Tags: docker, openshift, s2i

We are trying to set up an OpenShift flow as close to the defaults as possible, without having to use Jenkins.

So far I have managed to adapt a s2i-generated Dockerfile to our needs (to get the benefits of the s2i images) and set up a simple "oc new-app" pipeline which creates a build following a git repository pushing the generated docker image to an image stream and a deployment triggered by the image stream update pushing to a default pod.  This works well.

Now we want to additionally have this docker image pushed to an external docker repository (the RED HAT CONTAINER REGISTRY known by OpenShift) and I would essentially like to keep the existing flow instead of adapting it to use the external registry instead of the internal.

So, can I set up a "build" or something like it which does nothing but take that image and push it to the docker registry?   How do I set it up using the `oc` command?

Answer (score 3):

Would you like to push the image builded by `buildConfig` to external registry, right ?
I think the work flow is like this:[Using Docker Credentials for Private Registries](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#using-docker-credentials-for-private-registries).

- Create credential `secret`

```
$ oc create secret generic <secret_name> \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<path/to/.docker/config.json> \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

- Link the `secret` with `builder` `ServiceAccount`.
- Configure the build image push target in the `buildConfig` as follows.

```
spec:
  output:
    to:
      kind: DockerImage   
      name: external.registry.io/subpath/imagename:latest
    pushSecret:
      name: <secret_name>
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: Thank you.  I would prefer not to change the existing build config as created by "oc new-app" but instead add another one responsible for this only.

Comment: That’s a good idea, you can run “oc start-build” with your new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) command-line tool to copy container images from one docker registry to another without needing to build the image a second time.

This is an officially supported tool by Red Hat that is part of the [new suite of tools](https://medium.com/@doh_88292/reinvent-container-capabilities-with-cri-o-buildah-podman-6f22d7a61450) (buildah, podman, skopeo, etc) to support running OpenShift and Kubernetes on top of the daemonless cri-o container runtime instead of docker.

Either log in to the source and destination registries via `docker login` or use the `--src-creds` and `--dest-creds` flags.

```
skopeo copy \
  --src-creds=testuser:testpassword \
  --dest-creds=otheruser:otherpassword \
  docker://myregistrydomain.com:5000/dockerimage:tag \
  docker://mysecondregistrydomain.com:5000/dockerimage:tag
```